# htaccess redirect from non query url to query url

Tags: ee2, htaccess, query, redirects, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a url from a non-query version to a query version with EE.

I can get the redirect working properly on a .php flat-file, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^test.php$ /test.php?var=1&var=2 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

However, I can not get a normal EE url like this to work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^testpage$ /testpage?var=1&var=2 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I suspect it has to do with how EE handles queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a fairly robust set of [mod_rewrite .htaccess rules for EE](https://gist.github.com/Ottergoose/5534170); I've got a couple of rules in there that will deal with query strings, hopefully it'll solve your problem.

Note: you'll need all four of the cases I have in there, which should be a complete set of cases needed for query strings and removing index.php from the URL; those four cases would be used to replace whatever rules you have in place to handle that functionality now.

You may need to make a few minor tweaks, but, that Gist is pretty well documented; please let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Great! I'll look into this and see if that works.